# Get Remote IP In a Capistrano Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I am trying to write a custom capistrano task that compiles my assets locally and then uses rsync to push them up to the production server. The problem is I cannot figure out how to access the IP address of my app server when using using capistrano's `run_locally`.

Here is an excerpt from my `config/deploy.rb`:

```
server "[some_ip_address]", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true

...

namespace :assets do
  desc 'Run the precompile task locally and rsync with shared'
  task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do

    run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
    run_locally "rsync -zvrh --progress -e 'ssh -i #{ssh_options[:keys][0]}' public/assets #{user}@$CAPISTRANO:HOST$:#{shared_path}"
    puts "cleaning up locally compiled assets"
    run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:clean"
  end
end
```

The problem is that `$CAPISTRANO:HOST$` does not expand out to the ip. I know I could hard code it, but I would like to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define capistrano variable with host IP and reference it anywhere in capistrano scripts to keep them DRY:

```
set :host, "some IP addresss"
server host, :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
```

and in your task definition:

```
run_locally "... #{host} ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `run_locally` doesn't have the same string substitutions as `run`, so `$CAPISTRANO:HOST$` won't work.

If all you are trying to do is have your assets precompiled, you can put the following line in your `deploy.rb`:

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I was already using `load 'deploy/assets'` and precompiling the assets on the server was too slow. That is why I am trying to precompile locally and `rsync` them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getaddrinfo` in [Socket](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html#method-c-getaddrinfo) or [Addrinfo](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Addrinfo.html#method-c-getaddrinfo)?

```
1.9.3p125 :035 > Addrinfo::getaddrinfo('ya.ru', 'http', :INET, :STREAM)[0].ip_address
 => "93.158.134.203"
1.9.3p125 :037 > Socket::getaddrinfo('ya.ru', 'http', :INET, :STREAM)[0][3]
 => "93.158.134.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pry gem i've found such an option:

```
  run_locally %{bundle exec rake assets:precompile}
  roles[:web].servers.each do |web_server|
    run_locally %{rsync --recursive --times --rsh=ssh --compress --human-readable --progress public/assets #{user}@#{web_server.host}:#{shared_path}}
  end
  run_locally %{bundle exec rake assets:clean}
```

PS. i was trying to do the same thing and found this question :)

Another option is to look at is turbo-sprockets-rails3 gem.